# Minha função não está tendo o retorno esperado

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function qa($array = array()) {
    $a = $array;
    $sequencias = [];
    $ultima_seq = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($a)-1; ++$i) {
        if (($a[$i+1]-$a[$i]) == 1) {
            if (isset($sequencias[$ultima_seq])) {
                $sequencias[$ultima_seq][] = $a[$i+1];
            } else {
                $sequencias[$ultima_seq][0] = $a[$i];
                $sequencias[$ultima_seq][1] = $a[$i+1];
            }
        } else {
            $ultima_seq++;
        }
    }
    $total_sequencia = count($sequencias);
    return $total_sequencia;
}
```

Ela conta os blocos de sequências numéricas de um array, por exemplo:

```
$a = array(1,2,4,5,7,8);
$b = array(10,11,12,15,16,20,21,22,30,31,32);
```

- Em **$a** temos 3 blocos de sequências (1,2 - 4,5 - 7,8);
- Em **$b** temos 4 blocos de sequências (10,11,12 - 15,16 - 20,21,22 -
  30,31,32);

Para exemplo, utilizaremos os seguintes array`s:

```
$a_1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
$a_1_copia = array(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
$a_2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
$a_2_copia = array(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
$a_3 = array(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
$a_3_copia = array(01,02,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
```

O retorno que estou obtendo é o seguinte:

```
print_r(qa($a_1)); // 2
print_r(qa($a_1_copia)); // 3
print_r(qa($a_2)); // 2
print_r(qa($a_2_copia)); // 3
print_r(qa($a_3)); // 2
print_r(qa($a_3_copia)); // 3
```

Porém, todos os array's tem sequência **2**. Os que estão me retornando **3** ficam assim se utilizo *0* (zero) em suas dezenas.

Já quebrei a cabeça mas, estou deixando passar algo. Onde estou errando aqui?

Comment: O objetivo é contar a quantidade de sequencias contidas num array? Porque alguns arrays tem numeros a começar em `0`, como por exemplo `(01,02,...` ?

Comment: @Isac o objetivo é contar a quantidade de **blocos** de sequências, como expliquei ali em cima. Alguns arrays tem `0` porque eu coloquei para mostrar o erro que estou tendo.

Comment: O seu código parece me correto, excetuando os zeros à esquerda. [Veja aqui o resultado](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96537bee426db1f500ee2df268f5ba66c0ce052a)

Comment: @Isac o código funciona perfeitamente quando o array não tem `0` à esquerda. Mas a questão é exatamente essa, como ele poderia funcionar corretamente quando também houver `0` a esquerda?

Comment: Pelo simples fato que quando um número possui o zero à esquerda o PHP irá considerá-lo como base 8, um octal. Sendo octal, os valores `08` e `09` nem seriam números válidos para o PHP 7+; já se está rodando em versões anteriores, o PHP os converte para zero (porque para o PHP isso faz sentido).

Comment: Não percebo o porque dos zeros. Porque motivo tem que ter os zeros? Você está a interpretar de texto ? Se for o caso deve usar `intval` para interpretar a string como inteiro que só por si lhe resolve o problema

Comment: seu for está assim ++$i , não deveria ser $i++ ?